# Why $|e^{i x}- 1 - i x + x^2/2|\le \min(|x|^3/6, x^2)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

Why $|e^{i x}- 1 - i x + x^2/2|\le \min(|x|^3/6, x^2)$?

Here $i$ is the imaginary unit.

It seems from Taylor expansion of $e^{ix}$, but I do not know how to bound the remaining items after the third one.

Answer (score 0):

First, resolve $M(x)$, the majorizing function. The crossing point occurs where
$$
 \color{blue}{\frac{x^{3}}{6}} = x^{2} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x = 6.
$$

[image: bowls]

$$
  M(x) =
\begin{cases}
 x^{2} & x \le 6 \\
 \color{blue}{\frac{\lvert x \rvert^{3}}{6}} & x > 6
\end{cases}
$$

---

Next, resolve the target function
$$
 f(x) = e^{ix} - 1 - ix + \frac{1}{2}x^{2}
$$
The Maclaurin expansion for the exponential is
$$
 e^{ix} = 1 + ix -\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{i x^3}{6} +\frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{i x^5}{120} -\frac{x^6}{720} -\frac{i x^7}{5040} + \frac{x^8}{40320} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{9}\right)
$$
The target function simplifies to the "left overs" from the series:
$$
 f(x) = -\frac{i x^3}{6} +\frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{i x^5}{120} -\frac{x^6}{720} -\frac{i x^7}{5040} + \frac{x^8}{40320} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{9}\right)
$$